# Strange behavior of python's append?

Tags: python, append

```
size = input('Kirjainmäärä: ')
kirjaimet = "0ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

ruudukko = []
rivi = ['0']*(size*2-1)

for i in range(0,size): #produce n rows
    for y in range(0,i+1): #this row needs i+1 letters
        for z in range(0+i,size*2-1-i):
            rivi[z] = kirjaimet[size-i]
    print rivi, i
    ruudukko.append(rivi)
print ruudukko
```

So the code was supposed to produce number matrices of the format

```
input=4

output=

DDDDDDD
DCCCCCD
DCBBBCD
DCBABCD
```

so here's the output of the above code with input=5 (print rivi, i -part)

```
['E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E'] 0
['E', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'E'] 1
['E', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E'] 2
['E', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'] 3
['E', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'] 4
```

everythings ok so far, but then..

```
[['E', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], ['E', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], ['E', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], ['E', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], ['E', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']]
```

The appended list ruudukko comes out all filled with the object appended last!

What the hell's going on?

Comment: rivi is currently pointing to an array and so appending an array involves putting the array object in the last position. If you want to flatten into a single list, use the extend() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't appending five *different* lists to your result. You are appending the *same* list five times.

You can fix it by appending a *copy* of your list to the result:

```
ruudukko.append(rivi[:])
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/TxWM2)

Comment: Note that, because of this kind of bug, it's unusual in Python to create a full-sized list populated with nulls and then mutate it. More usual would be to say `rivi = []` at the start of each row and `rivi.append( kirjaimet[size-i] )` in the z-loop, as OP did with the `ruudukko` list.

Answer (score 2):

`list.append()` stores a reference to the object appended. So you have stored multiple references to your list `rivi` in your list `ruudukko`. Naturally, since they are all actually the same object, when you change one, it changes everywhere it is referenced.

Make a fresh `rivi` list each time through your loop.

This behavior is not strange; it is normal and expected and should be covered in any decent Python tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You are putting the same object in the list `ruudukko` five times. So each of the 5 items of `ruudukko` are in fact bound to the same object.

Because `list` is a mutable type, you are able to modify it and every other reference to that same object appear to be modified also. Of course it's only one object being modified, it just looks to you as though each item in `ruudukko` has been modified. That's not the case, the same object appears there five times.

In order to fix this you need to create a new list object each time you append to `ruudukko`. There are lots of ways to do this, for example you could do it like this:

```
ruudukko.append(list(rivi))
```

The most simple example I can think of that illustrates the behaviour of mutable objects is this:

```
>>> a = [0]
>>> b = a
>>> b[0] = 1
>>> a
[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You've only declared `rivi` one time, then repeatedly reassigned its value.  You have this single object, which is mutable, appended repeatedly into your outer list `ruudukko`.  Because the object is mutable and you're not copying it you end up with the final value in every position in `ruudukko`.