# All possible random tiles in 2048

Tags: python, arrays, append

I am trying to make a function that takes in a 2048 board (nested lists making a 4 by 4 grid), like this,

```
[[0, 2, 2, 2], 
 [2, 2, 2, 2], 
 [2, 2, 2, 2], 
 [2, 2, 2, 2]]
```

Note: I know this isn't a realistic 2048 board, but I chose the example for simplicity

and the function should output a list of all of the places a random tile could appear(either a 2 or a 4)

For example, if I run the function on the board above, the output should be.

```
[[[2, 2, 2, 2], 
  [2, 2, 2, 2], 
  [2, 2, 2, 2], 
  [2, 2, 2, 2]], 

 [[4, 2, 2, 2], 
  [2, 2, 2, 2], 
  [2, 2, 2, 2], 
  [2, 2, 2, 2]]]
```

So anywhere were there is a 0, we want to make one board where there 0 has been replaced by a 2 and another where it has been replaced by a 4.

Here is my code so far.

```
def all_rand_tiles(state):
    states = []
    changed = []
    old_states = [None]
    while old_states != states:
        old_states = states
        new_state = state
        for row in range(4):
            for tile in range(4):
                if state[row][tile] == 0:

                    #AREA WITH PROBLEM BELOW THIS LINE
                    if [row, tile] not in changed:
                        new_state[row][tile] = 2
                        states.append(new_state)

                        new_state[row][tile] = 4
                        states.append(new_state)
                        changed.append([row, tile])

    return states
```

The problem is that when I append the two different states in the final if statement, both states have the zero changed to a 4. So the output of the function if you run it on the board at the top will look like this.

```
[[[4, 2, 2, 2], 
  [2, 2, 2, 2], 
  [2, 2, 2, 2], 
  [2, 2, 2, 2]], 

 [[4, 2, 2, 2], 
  [2, 2, 2, 2], 
  [2, 2, 2, 2], 
  [2, 2, 2, 2]]]
```

When I run `new_state[row][tile] = 4` the state I just created is changed for having a 2 in it, to have a 4.

You can see the problem demonstrated if you print `new_state` before and after running `new_state[row][tile] = 4` in the bad code area.

I am incredibly confused by this and I have no idea why I am having this stupid problem.

**EDIT: Please try out your solutions before posting. I have given you the only function I am working with `all_rand_tiles` and so far I have been unable to fix the problem with any of the answers that have been presented.**

Comment: @jonrsharpe Please elaborate.

Comment: The short answer is probably "referential equality". As a simple example, `a = []; b = a; b.append(23); print a` will print `[23]` even though you didn't make any apparent changes to `a` after creating it.

Comment: This board you're replacing a `0` on is from immediately after you swipe, right?

Comment: @TheSoundDefense Correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must create a copy of `state` and set it with  `new_state` . because of you have a `2D array` you must use `deepcopy` so change your code to this :

```
from copy import deepcopy


state=[[0, 0, 2, 2], 
   [2, 2, 2, 2], 
   [2, 2, 2, 2], 
   [2, 2, 2, 2]]

def all_rand_tiles(state):
    states = []
    changed = []
    old_states = [None]
    while old_states != states:
        old_states = states
        new_state = deepcopy(state)
        for row in range(4):
            for tile in range(4):
                if state[row][tile] == 0:

                    if [row, tile] not in changed:
                        new_state[row][tile] = 2
                        states.append(new_state)
                        new_state = deepcopy(state)

                        new_state[row][tile] = 4
                        states.append(new_state)
                        new_state = deepcopy(state)
                        changed.append([row, tile])

    return states

print all_rand_tiles(state)
```

DEMO:

```
[[[2, 0, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2], 
 [2, 2, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2]],

 [[4, 0, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2]],

 [[0, 2, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2]]

[[0, 4, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2]]]
```

Comment: Awesome! This is a much simpler version of the very long explanation I just gave. (I hope we both get up-votes.)

Comment: I modified the code to use this copy function, but the issue persists. You can run the code here if you don't believe me. http://labs.codecademy.com/

Comment: because i haven't whole of your code i cant try any thing .

Comment: @DavidGreydanus i edit code and it work fine excuse for delay ...also i gave +1 for your good question !

Comment: @Kasra Big step in the right direction, but if you have more than one 0 in the board, this function doesn't give all of the possibilites and instead repeats itself.

Comment: Even so, that is a separate problem I think so I accepted your answer. Thanks for the help.

Comment: well come and thanks ... i think on this problem too ! if i got an answer i will give it to you !

Comment: @Kasra I made a small edit to your code to give it the desired behavior. Thx for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when you call `states.append(new_state)` you are appending a **reference**  to new_state to the list, not a **copy**.  Hence, any modifications made to the new_state object will affect all references to it.  In order to get the behavior you want, you need to make your modification to new state and then append a copy of the list with that state to the new_states object.  There are several ways to do this:

```
states.append(new_state[:]) # slice the list
states.append(copy.copy(new_state)) # use the copy function
states.append(list(new_state)) # explicitly construct a new list
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Python specifically, but I've been programming about 20 years so my answer might actually make sense.  You append the array twice, in the following code:

```
if [row, tile] not in changed:
    new_state[row][tile] = 2
    states.append(new_state)   <--- appended the first time here

    new_state[row][tile] = 4
    states.append(new_state)   <--- appended the second time here
    changed.append([row, tile])
```

Is it appending the new_state array itself, or just a REFERENCE to the new_state array?  If it's a reference to the new_state array, then both instances will be the same, since both references are referring to the latest version of new_state (which has a "4" in that row & tile).

If that's the cause, then the solution is to make an actual copy / clone of the array, or just copy each of the values in new_state individually to a new array, before you use states.append.

Comment: as a guy that is not familiar with python i admire you for your answer ! ;)

Comment: Thanks @Kasra! I've run into this same issue in other languages, so I thought it might apply. :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're running into the same issue as found in the question [Strange behavior of python's append?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896370/strange-behavior-of-pythons-append) . You're appending the same new_state twice, modifying the single copy each time.